Дочерние объекты не экспортируются из Blender
При попытке экспорта модели в формате fbx в сборку не включаются любые объекты, которые имеют 3 уровень (и ниже) вложенности в родителей:
1уров.- Тело (идёт в сборку)
2уров.-- Рука (идёт в сборку)
3уров.--- Палец (не идёт в сборку).
Если Палец убрать из дочернего объекта (переместить на второй уровень), то тогда он попадёт в сборку.
Пробовал создать новый проект. При создании иерархии из примитивов возникает та же проблема - из 3 кубов в сборку попадает только 2.
Как сделать, чтобы в сборку включались все объекты иерархии, а не только 2 уровня?

добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! как создать минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример
